# Why "are having" has been used?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In Korea. because many companies are having labor disputes, they are not able to work properly.

Is this sentence correct? If I say - "In Korea many companies have labour disputes, they are not able to work properly", what differences in meaning of sentences will arise?

Why in given example "are having" has been used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Present Continuous and it's used because they wanted to describe an action "which is happening now, in the present, but not necessary right now".

So these companies "are having many disputes in the present".

For example,

I am having exams. (not right now, but this month, time of exams)

It's important to know that Present Continues describes temporary actions, not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

As Standalone's post says, the use of the present continuous *are having* stresses that the disputes are happening 'now', where *now* may be considered as either right now, or during a period of time around now.

This sense of time *now* contrasts with a general idea of present time. It contrasts with ideas like *generally*, *usually*, *always*. So in the Original Poster's sentence, the phrase:

- many companies **are having** labor disputes,

... may imply that these disputes started happening recently or that they did not happen before. However, it is important to understand that this is only an implication, it just gives us that idea. The important thing is that the writer is thinking about the disputes as happening at the current time.